# Flask-Postman-Python : POST method fails but GET method works

Tags: python, flask, postman

I'm getting an error while running POST method in flask using Postman, how do I resolve this? Only POST method is not working, I'm also using GET method which is working fine, when I enter "/transactions/new" with my localhost on my browser it throws an error, otherwise it's working fine.

```
@app.route('/transactions/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_transaction():
    values = request.get_json()

    
    required = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount']
    if not all(k in values for k in required):
        return 'Missing values', 400

    
    index = blockchain.new_transaction(values['sender'], values['recipient'],values['amount'])

    response = {'message': f'Transaction will be added to Block {index}'}
    return jsonify(response), 201
```

The error is given below when I run this particular function:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2022 18:27:30] "GET /transactions/new HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Have another function with POST method, which also doesn't work, but all the functions with GET method are working well...

Comment: Please show your JSON post body. Otherwise, `values` is empty, so yes, you explicitly return 400 status

Comment: Do you mean the body of new_transaction() function from `index = blockchain.new_transaction(values['sender'], values['recipient'],values['amount'])`

Comment: No. Your postman request... What json are you providing? Also, GET requests don't have bodies, so what exactly are you expecting `request.get_json()` to return? The log you've shown isn't an error

Comment: I'm actually new to this, but the code I've provided is what it is on the whole, and another related snippet is :
`def new_transaction(self, sender, recipient, amount):
        self.current_transactions.append({
            'sender': sender,
            'recipient': recipient,
            'amount': amount,
        })

        return self.last_block['index'] + 1`

I'm sorry, I don't know what you're talking about, is this enough? thanks.

Comment: You said "flask using Postman". Postman has nothing to do with Python, so no. Please show what JSON you've given to Postman, not more Python code. You also said GET in your browser works, which I don't think it does because no JSON will be there either, and you're always running `return 'Missing values', 400`... Put print statements in your code and debug it